# Как использовать элемент keygen?

Tags: html

В [спеках](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/keygen) написано, что он используется для шифрования данных формы. Но в дебаггере все данные открыты, а передаётся помимо данных ещё и ключ. Тогда и смысл в нём?

Comment: Всё, что есть на стороне клиента, доступно ему так или иначе.

Comment: @ReklatsMaster

      Но в дебаггере все данные открыты

Т.е. эти манипуляции должны быть скрыты от пользователя? Чтобы от, гад, ни в коем случае не просёк?

Comment: > Тогда и смысл в нём?

Смысл в том, чтобы отдать серверу открытый ключ, а закрытый хранить у себя. Пользователь ведь имеет право владеть своими закрытыми ключами, не так ли?

Comment: @alexlz Вы не поверите, но я проверил вашу теорию с помощью Fiddler`a. Результат тот же. Отдельно ключ и нешифрованные данные формы.

Comment: @Nofate Ну отдам я серверу открытый ключ. А дальше-то что?

Answer (score 1):

Он сам по себе не шифрует данные, он только создает связку открытого и закрытого ключа. А дальше вам решать как им пользоваться - шифровать им сообщения или подпись.

Т.е. сервер и ваш клиент должны сами реализовать шифрование своих данных этим ключом и все дальнейшие коммуникации вести с помощью него.

Как происходит шифрование с открытым ключом можно посмотреть тут - [Криптосистема с открытым ключом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BC)